# Controlling line color and line type in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Background**

In Germany, there are 16 federal states, ten of which belonged to West Germany, six of which belonged to East Germany. In some respects, for example mortality rates of certain cancers, there are persistent differences between the ten former western states and the six former eastern ones. There are also differences among the states within the respective groups.

To show the differences among the states, it can make a certain amount of sense to plot data, for example age-standardized breast cancer mortality by year, from each state. A plot with 16 lines is not always a good choice, and I don't want to open up a discussion about that. Sometimes the powers that be say that's how it has to be.

**The problem**

Differentiating among 16 lines on a plot can be difficult. To do so, I usually use a combination of colors from the `RColorBrewer` package (the first ten colors of `Set3` plus the first six colors of that palette again, corresponding to the ten former west and six former east states) and line types (one line type for east, one for west). Using the `lattice` package, a plot of age-standardized breast cancer mortality rates from 1998-2010 by state could look like this:

[image: xyplot that works]

**The question**

I would like to do a similar plot using `ggplot`, but I haven't figured out how to combine the colors and the line types in the legend. So far, I've gotten this far:

[image: unsatisfactory ggplot]

If it is possible to combine colors and line types in `ggplot` legends, how does one go about doing it?

Here's the code to create the data frame and the plots:

```
mort3 <- structure(list(State = structure(c(8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 
11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 
1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 
14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 
7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 
11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 
1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 
14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 
7L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L), class = "factor", .Label = c("SH", 
"HH", "NI", "HB", "NW", "HE", "RP", "BW", "BY", "SL", "BE", "BB", 
"MV", "SN", "ST", "TH")), BCmort = c(16.5, 16.6, 15, 14.4, 13.5, 
17.1, 15.8, 16.3, 18.3, 16.8, 17, 18.1, 13.1, 15.1, 18.8, 13.1, 
16.4, 16.1, 15.8, 12.8, 16.3, 19.2, 16.8, 13, 17.9, 17, 19.4, 
19.4, 13.1, 13.8, 18.1, 13.8, 15.9, 17.3, 17.5, 13.7, 17.4, 17.5, 
16.7, 15.5, 18.1, 18, 20.1, 19.1, 11.8, 14.6, 18.2, 13.4, 16.8, 
17.5, 15.6, 14.1, 13.9, 18.2, 17.1, 15.2, 18.1, 16.6, 19.3, 18.6, 
13.1, 14.6, 19.6, 12.4, 16.6, 17.8, 17.5, 14.3, 20.5, 19.2, 19, 
12.6, 19.5, 17.8, 19.2, 21, 14.4, 13.4, 19.8, 14, 17.5, 18.9, 
16.4, 14.7, 17.7, 20.1, 18.5, 14.5, 19.1, 19.2, 20.1, 19.7, 14.2, 
16.2, 17.9, 12.6, 18, 18.7, 17.7, 16.5, 16.6, 20.3, 18.1, 15.2, 
19, 20, 19.8, 21.3, 13.8, 14.8, 20.4, 14.8, 18.2, 18.7, 16.9, 
16.2, 20.2, 20.4, 18.5, 14, 20.2, 18.7, 20.3, 17.7, 14.4, 14.5, 
21.7, 13.7, 18.3, 19.7, 17.8, 16.5, 20.2, 21.7, 18.8, 16.7, 20.4, 
20, 19.6, 22.9, 15.2, 14.9, 21.7, 14.6, 18.3, 19.7, 17, 16.7, 
22.9, 16.2, 19.6, 15.9, 20.3, 19.9, 18.9, 21.8, 14.9, 18, 21.4, 
16.1, 19.6, 19.2, 19.1, 16.7, 20, 18.2, 20.5, 15.5, 20.5, 21.1, 
21.3, 23.8, 15.8, 15.3, 21.3, 15.7, 19.6, 20.3, 19.2, 17.4, 18.1, 
23.1, 20.6, 16.2, 21.5, 20.3, 21.4, 20.8, 16.1, 15.8, 22.1, 14.5, 
20, 20.2, 19, 18.7, 23.1, 21.8, 19.4, 17.4, 20.9, 20.5, 20.4, 
23.2, 16.3, 17.6, 23.1, 16.5), year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998), eastWest = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("west", 
"east"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("State", "BCmort", "year", 
"eastWest"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -208L))

colVec<-c(brewer.pal(10,"Set3"),brewer.pal(6,"Set3"))
ltyVec<-rep(c("solid","dashed"),c(10,6))

ggplot(mort3, aes(x = year, y = BCmort, col = State, lty = eastWest)) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(west = "solid", east = "dashed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(10, "Set3"), brewer.pal(6, "Set3"))) +
  opts(title = "BC mortality")

xyplot(BCmort ~ year, data = mort3, groups = State, lty = ltyVec,
  type = "l", col = colVec, lwd = 2,
  key = list(lines = list(lty = ltyVec, col = colVec, lwd = 2),
  text = list(levels(mort3$State)), columns = 1,
  space = "right", title = "State"), grid = TRUE, main = "BC mortality")
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The trick is to map both `colour` and `linetype` to `State`, and then to define `scale_linetype_manual` with 16 levels:

```
ggplot(mort3, aes(x = year, y = BCmort, col = State, linetype = State)) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(rep("solid", 10), rep("dashed", 6))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(10, "Set3"), brewer.pal(6, "Set3"))) +
  opts(title = "BC mortality") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @BenBarnes Actually, it's you who reminded me of `linetype`. I simply noticed that although your scale was `linetype`, the mapping was to `lty` - in `ggplot2` these usually have the same name.

Comment: I see now about the mappings. Mapping both the color and line type to State is what I did for `xyplot`, too. Thanks very much for the `ggplot` way!