# Collapse ggplot2 legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

Edit:
I spent a lot of time typing this up, but got feedback that my question wasn't clear, so I'm editing in an attempt to clarify.

Take the below code and run it. Note that the third plot has two legends. I want to make the third plot look like the second plot without having to hard code everything like I did to create the second plot.

Original post:
I'm trying to show data about multiple companies and their products over time.

The basic graph (chart 1) is a bit hard to follow with just color, especially once I add a couple more companies.

So, I'm trying to drive the color off company and the linetype off product.

I can control it manually (chart 2), but this seems like a poor solution.

I can do it automatically (chart 3), but there are a couple problems:
- I'm no longer sure how to control the color without going full manual again
- I get two legends

I searched and saw online that you can remove the legends by having the titles and names the same. But this requires naming everything manually, which I'm trying to avoid, because if a new company or product comes along, the chart won't work any longer.

Any advice on how to handle this dynamically would be greatly appreciated.
As an aside, I'd be curious to know how ggplot2 handles labels or colors when they're assigned manually. There seems to be nothing to tie the data to the order of the colors or names, so I'm left to believe that if you re-ordered the data or got new data your names could be incorrect?

```
# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

marketShareDF <- structure(list(Company = c("Company1", "Company1", "Company1", 
                                         "Company1", "Company1", "Company1", "Company1", "Company1", "Company1", 
                                         "Company1", "Company1", "Company1", "Company2", "Company2", "Company2", 
                                         "Company2", "Company2", "Company2", "Company2", "Company2", "Company2", 
                                         "Company3", "Company3", "Company3", "Company3", "Company3", "Company3", 
                                         "Company3", "Company3"), 
                             Product = c("ProductA", "ProductA", 
                                         "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductB", 
                                         "ProductB", "ProductB", "ProductB", "ProductB", "ProductA", "ProductA", 
                                         "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductB", 
                                         "ProductB", "ProductA", "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductB", "ProductB", 
                                         "ProductB", "ProductB", "ProductB"), 
                             Combined = c("Co1ProductA", 
                                          "Co1ProductA", "Co1ProductA", "Co1ProductA", "Co1ProductA", "Co1ProductA", 
                                          "Co1ProductB", "Co1ProductB", "Co1ProductB", "Co1ProductB", "Co1ProductB", 
                                          "Co1ProductB", "Co2ProductA", "Co2ProductA", "Co2ProductA", "Co2ProductA", 
                                          "Co2ProductA", "Co2ProductA", "Co2ProductB", "Co2ProductB", "Co2ProductB", 
                                          "Co3ProductA", "Co3ProductA", "Co3ProductB", "Co3ProductB", "Co3ProductB", 
                                          "Co3ProductB", "Co3ProductB", "Co3ProductB"), 
                             Year = c(2010, 
                                      2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
                                      2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2011, 
                                      2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 
                             PercentOfMarket = c(0.08, 
                                                 0.046, 0.035, 0.032, 0.018, 0.007, 0.163, 0.142, 0.127, 0.111, 
                                                 0.163, 0.112, 0.084, 0.083, 0.079, 0.064, 0.043, 0.006, 0.011, 
                                                 0.546, 0.413, 0.088, 0.294, 0.129, 0.141, 0.17, 0.185, 0.166, 
                                                 0.073), 
                             c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                               NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                               NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                               NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                               NA_real_, NA_real_)), 
                        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -29L), 
                        .Names = c("Company", "Product", "Combined", "Year", "PercentOfMarket", ""))

#Basic chart
marketShareDF %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(Year, PercentOfMarket, group=Combined, color=Combined, linetype=Combined))

# Color by company, lines by Product - manual
marketShareDF %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(Year, PercentOfMarket, group=Combined, color=Combined, linetype=Combined)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,1,2,1,2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green"))

# Color by company, lines by Product - automatic
marketShareDF %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(Year, PercentOfMarket, group=Combined, color=Company, linetype=Product))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I just spent 5 minutes on this and still have no idea. Please clarify your question-- specifying colors? line types? scales / legends? It's unclear. I think this can be solved with `guides(<xxx> = NULL)` but I don't understand the question.

Comment: I am sorry. I will work to reword it. I probably spent two hours putting it together.

Comment: @Alex - I tried to clarify. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be used?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
marketShareDF %>% ggplot() +
        geom_line(lwd = 1,aes(Year, PercentOfMarket,group=Combined, color=Combined, linetype=Combined)) +
        scale_linetype_manual(values = c(rep("solid", 3), rep("dashed", 3))) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(3, "Set3"),brewer.pal(3, "Set3")))
```

[image]

adapted from [Controlling line color and line type in ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344561/controlling-line-color-and-line-type-in-ggplot-legend)