# ggplot2: Specifying a linetype with a column value

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Question/problem

Well, I am almost there, but there is still one or two things I want to solve/understand.

I am trying to plot a series of `geom_smooth()`'s by `data.table`'s column `PlotCat` specifying two distinct linetypes by another variable, `PlotLine`.

I am struggling with a neat solution with linetypes visible on the legend.

#### Setup

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)


dataT <- data.table(
  X = c(13.24, 22.8, 29.79, 32.13, 35.02, 40.8, 48.05, 59.89, 7.24, 18.33, 25.86, 29.74, 38.5, 48.5, 55.99, 6.71, 12.36, 22.8, 27.99, 41.11, 53.88, 61.34, 7.83, 23.85, 31.89, 37.38, 48.35, 59.62, 60.28, 5.8, 10.12, 18.12, 22.5, 32.98, 44.58, 51.39, 13.61, 19.41, 23.77, 27.5, 34.66, 39.63, 51.63, 1.06, 14.39, 20.2, 23.34, 31.56, 36.96, 50.94, 14.38, 26.85, 34.49, 39.33, 51.74, 60.11, 64.83),
  Y = c(0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01),
  PlotCat = c("Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 0", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Control 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 1", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 2", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 3", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 4", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 5", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6", "Model Cat 6"),
  PlotLine = c("dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "dashed", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid"))

# Sample of rows:
#         X    Y     PlotCat PlotLine
#  1: 13.24 0.02   Control 0   dashed
# 11: 25.86 0.01   Control 1   dashed
# 22: 61.34 0.04 Model Cat 1    solid
# 28: 59.62 0.02 Model Cat 2    solid
# 34: 32.98 0.01 Model Cat 3    solid
# 46: 20.20 0.02 Model Cat 5    solid
```

#### Desired plot

Based on accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344561/controlling-line-color-and-line-type-in-ggplot-legend), but manual specification of `linetype` values is ugly.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(dataT),
             aes(x = X,
                 y = Y,
                 colour = PlotCat,
                 linetype = PlotCat)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.5, fill = NA) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(rep("dashed", dataT[PlotLine == "dashed", length(unique(PlotCat))]),
                                   rep("solid", dataT[PlotLine == "solid", length(unique(PlotCat))]))) + 
  ggtitle("Desired plot")
g1
```

[image: Desired plot]

#### Closest I can get without manually specifying values

```
dataT[, PlotLine := factor(PlotLine, levels = c("solid", "dashed"))]

g2 <- ggplot(data.frame(dataT),
             aes(x = X,
                 y = Y,
                 colour = PlotCat,
                 linetype = PlotLine)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.5, fill = NA) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_linetype(guide = FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Almost there...")
g2
```

[image: Almost there...]

#### Issues I want to solve/understand

1. Somehow indicate `linetype` on the legend of **Almost there...** (see `Control 0` and `Control 1` on the **Desired plot**);
2. Get the same linetype of `Control 0` and `Control 1` on **Desired plot** and **Almost there...** - this is probably related to the `levels` of the `factor(PlotLine)`, I tried to add more of them to "push" `"dashed"` into higher levels, but got no visible changes on the plots.

Any hints?

Comment: @jf328, it will circle through all linetypes, I just want two - solid and dashed (and be able to change them easily).

Comment: 1. I don't know if you can combine them. You can however have another legend if you don't specify `guide=FALSE`

2. You are right. ggplot uses factor level. You can reorder the levels however you want and get type you want
`dataT[, PlotLine2 := reorder(PlotLine, PlotLine == 'dashed')]`

Comment: @jf328, ad 1: I have used `guide=FALSE` to not print two legends, so clearly I am looking for another answer than just getting it back. Ad 2: reordering PlotLine unfortunately gives exactly same plot.

Comment: Then try `reorder(PlotLine, PlotLine == 'solid')`, one will work :)

Comment: @jf328, looks like using a factor is not an answer here, as it still gives line type showed on the second plot (i.e. slightly narrower dashed), so it does not change anything - I still had to use `scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed"), guide = FALSE)` to get the line type matching the first plot. It is a bit confusing, I will try to dig more into it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to combine two scales without using scale_*_manual. However, there's a generic solution unsing only information form PlotCat:

```
dataT$PlotCat = factor(dataT$PlotCat)

ggplot(data.frame(dataT), aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=PlotCat, linetype=PlotCat)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.5, fill = NA) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=as.numeric(grepl("Control", levels(dataT$PlotCat)))+1)
```

Comment: This is slightly limited (imagine writing those `ifelse`'s for more groups...), but definitely better than replicating the linetype values, thank you. Lets wait a bit more for other solutions.

Comment: You can use the numeric representation of the factor levels (see the edited solution). That way it's independent of the number of groups.

Comment: How would you add other groups to your solution? Let's say we want to plot "Control 0" with dashed, "Control 1" with dotted and all the "Model Cat X" with solid line. I have "patched" sapply, grepl and max together, but the solution is long, ugly and there must be something better than that: `dataT$PlotCat = factor(dataT$PlotCat);
keys <- c("Model", "Control 1", "Control 0");
cats <- levels(dataT$PlotCat);
linetypes <- sapply(1:length(keys), function(i) {
  as.numeric(grepl(keys[i], cats, ignore.case=TRUE)) * i
}) %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>% summarise_each(funs(max(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% t()`