# Combine aesthetics (e.g. shapes, colors, and linetypes) in ggplot2 to increase visual palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with 30 factors from which I am making a scatter plot. I want to combine `shape` and `color` so that I don't end up using 30 colors (which, of course, are basically undistinguishable from each other when the palette is so large - see example).

The idea would be to **use 7-8 colors combined with 4 shapes to create an unique assignment for each factor**. On the plot below, for example, we could have factors 1-8 as squares, 9-16 as triangles, 17-24 as circles, and 25-30 as diamonds.

```
# Example code
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(my_x = rnorm(n = 30, -0.2, 0.2),
                my_y = rnorm(n = 30,  0.2, 0.2),
                my_labels = as.character(1:30))
ggplot(d, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y, color = my_labels, shape = my_labels)) + 
  geom_abline() +
  geom_point() +
  lims(x = c(-1,1), y = c(-1,1))
```

[image: My_plot]

I thought about creating some custom aesthetic mapping that encompasses those two levels, but this doesn't seem to be a trivial task from what I've searched so far. I tried adding two columns with repeating factors, `d$color` and `d$shape` and use them in the `aes( )` call, but then I can't combine the legends.

```
# Add color-shape mapping
d$color <- as.character(c(rep(c(1:8), 3), c(1:6)))
d$shape <- as.character(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8), rep(3,8), rep(4,6)))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question uses color and linetype but the same thing should work for color and shape i would think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344561/controlling-line-color-and-line-type-in-ggplot-legend

Comment: Agree. Not an exact duplicate but if insufficiently similar, then an explanation of what barrier to implementation remains needs to be added to the question body using the [edit] capacity provided by the SO interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That question's title was off enough that I couldn't find it earlier. I'm changing mine to make it easier for other users finding this answer.
Answering my own question, one should add `scale_shape_manual(values = c(rep(15,8), rep(16,8), rep(17,8), rep(18,6))) + scale_color_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(10, "Paired"), brewer.pal(10, "Paired"), brewer.pal(10, "Paired")))` to the example code.