# R - ggplot custom legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created graph in ggplot in R, I'm actually pretty happy about it except the legend, I'd like to have just legend with colour and linetype variations inside it.

My code is:

```
x <- data.frame(
    "type" = c("new", "new", "old", "old", "new", "new", "old", "old"), 
    "date" = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08")),
    "score" = c("1.5", "2.5", "2.6", "3.7", "5.2", "8.6", "5.2", "8.6"),
    "category" = c("actual", "predicted", "actual", "predicted", "actual", "predicted", "actual", "predicted"),
    stringsAsFactors = F)

  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(x, aes(x=date, y=score, group = paste(category, type), linetype = category, colour = paste(category, type))) + 
    geom_line(size = 1.25) +
    scale_color_manual(
      values = c("#4286f4", "#f9026d", "#4286f4", "#f9026d")
    )
```

Result should be

[image: proposed image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following does what the question asks for. It is inspired in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396292/controlling-linetype-color-and-label-in-ggplot-legend). The trick is to make the `labels` and scale `name` equal for both `scale_color_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual`.
I have `paste`ed the columns `category` and `type` begorehand in order to make the code simpler.

```
library(ggplot2)

colr <- paste(x$category, x$type)

ggplot(x, aes(x = date, y = score, 
              group = colr, 
              linetype = colr, 
              colour = colr)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.25) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("#4286f4", "#f9026d", "#4286f4", "#f9026d"),
    labels = sort(unique(colr)),
    name = "category and type"
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 3, 3),
                        labels = sort(unique(colr)),
                        name = "category and type")
```

[image]