# Combining linetype and color in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataframe like this :

```
> head(df_graph)
   treatment year      mean         se
1:        AC 2005 0.3626147 0.03005057
2:        AC 2006 0.3925465 0.02370335
3:        AC 2007 0.3217444 0.02279881
4:        AC 2008 0.3895656 0.05985077
5:        AC 2009 0.3820191 0.01481586
6:        AC 2010 0.3732695 0.03544626
...
```

And a (long) ggplot script :

```
df_graph %>% 

  # way to make 2 lines becoming 4 in a smooth way
  filter(treatment %in% c("Ambient", "Elevated")) %>%
  mutate(treatment = ifelse(treatment == "Ambient", "AA", "EE")) %>%
  bind_rows(df_graph) %>%
  mutate(treatment_group = ifelse(treatment %in% c("Ambient", "AC", "AF", "AA"),"treatment1","treatment2"),
         line_type = ifelse(treatment %in% c("AA", "EE", "AF", "EF"),"type1","type2")) %>%

  # plot
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = mean,group = interaction(treatment_group, line_type),color = treatment_group)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = mean, linetype = line_type),size = 1.5, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(size=5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se),width = 0.2, size = 1.5)+

  # scaling visual
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue1','red3'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed', 'solid'))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1999:2010), limits = c(1998.5, 2010.5),labels = 1999:2010)+

  # axes and legend
  labs(title ="", x="year", y = expression(paste("result")))+
  theme_classic() + theme(text = element_text(size=20))
```

I made it this way so that 2 treatments can become 4 after 2004. My problem concerns my legend. By running this script, I get a 'two parts' legend with 1) the color (treatment_group) and the 2) the line type (line_type).

What I need is a legend with only the 4 treatments displayed after 2004.

What I get:
[image: wrong legend]

What I would like to get (ideally):
[image: better legend]

I realize my dataframe is not the best format, but to get a smooth transition from 2004 to 2005, that's the only way I found. Hence a good solution would be changing the ggplot script, not the shape of the dataframe.

I've seen this : [Controlling line color and line type in ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344561/controlling-line-color-and-line-type-in-ggplot-legend)

But it will also add the 'ambient' and 'elevated' treatment, and so duplicate the straight lines in the legend. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach for you. I created a sample data given your data above was not enough to reproduce your graphic. I'd like to give credit to the SO users who posted answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140266/how-to-merge-color-line-style-and-shape-legends-in-ggplot). The key trick in this post was to assign identical groups to shape and line type. Similarly, I needed to do the same for color and linetype in your case. In addition to that there was one more thing do to. I manually assigned specific colors and line types. Here, there are four levels (i.e., treatment1.AC, treatment1.AE, treatment2.EC, treatment2.EF) in the end. But I used `interaction()` and created eight levels. Hence, I needed to specify eight colors and line types. When I assigned a name to the legend, I realized that I need to have an identical name in both `scale_color_manual()` and `scale_linetype_manual()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(111)

mydf <- data.frame(year = rep(1999:2010, time = 4),
                   treatment.type = rep(c("AC", "AF", "EC", "EF"), each = 12),
                   treatment = rep(c("treatment1", "treatment2"), each = 24),
                   mean = c(runif(min = 0.3, max = 0.55, 12),
                            rep(NA, 5), runif(min = 0.3, max = 0.55, 7),
                            runif(min = 0.3, max = 0.55, 12),
                            rep(NA, 5), runif(min = 0.3, max = 0.55, 7)),
                   se = c(runif(min = 0.01, max = 0.03, 12),
                           rep(NA, 5), runif(min = 0.01, max = 0.03, 7),
                           runif(min = 0.01, max = 0.03, 12),
                           rep(NA, 5), runif(min = 0.01, max = 0.03, 7)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = year, y = mean,
                    color = interaction(treatment, treatment.type),
                    linetype = interaction(treatment, treatment.type))) +
geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
geom_line() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se),width = 0.1, size = 0.5) +
scale_color_manual(name = "Treatment conditions", values = rep(c("blue", "blue", "red", "red"), times = 2)) +
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment conditions", values = rep(c(1,2), times = 4))
```

[image]

Comment: @Y.Coch Pleasure to help you.