# legend not showing up ggplot2 with 2 x-axis

Tags: ggplot2

I try to create a graph with 4 lines and 1 bar series and 2 different x-axes, and I am getting the plot but the legend is not showing. What could be the problem?

my variables are

```
tempf = aggregate(list(fe = WECC$prc_fe), list(fyear = factor(WE$FYEAR)), mean)
tempc1 = aggregate(list(cn = WECC$prc_cn), list(fyear = factor(WE$FYEAR)), mean)
```

and analogous for tempc2, 3, 4

```
ggplot(tempf, aes(x = fyear, y = fem, group=1))+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = fyear, y = fem), stat = "identity", fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(data=tempc1, aes(x = fyear, y = cn, group=1), linetype = "dotted", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=tempc2, aes(x = fyear, y = ce, group=1), linetype = "dashed", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=tempc3, aes(x = fyear, y = cl, group=1), linetype = "longdash", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=tempc4, aes(x = fyear, y = cm, group=1), linetype = "dotdash", size=1) +
  xlab("Years under research") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "v", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Mean"))+
  ggtitle("Yearly means")+
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "grey75"))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of the data?

Comment: What variable(s) do you expect to be in the legend?

Comment: my variables are yearly means of panel data variables - is that helpful enough?

Comment: I'm totally going for a guess here because you didn't specify what should be in the legend, nor gave a bit of data that makes you code reproducible, but; you probably want the `linetype = ...` inside the mapping `aes()` call.

Comment: that actually helped and solved the problem! Thank you so much @teunbrand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining linetype and color in ggplot2 legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450762/combining-linetype-and-color-in-ggplot2-legend)